# Uniform Boundary for S.D.E with Lipschitz Coefficients

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, lipschitz-functions, stochastic-differential-equations

Edit of progress:
Since the SDE is linear, I got a solution in the form of $e^\int...$$\cdot e^\int$.
By Jensen's inequality I can change the order of the left factor to have the integral on the outside. 
Am I correct in my method, and if so what should I do next?

Let $X_t^x$ be a solution to the SDE: $dX_t=b(X_t)+\sigma(X_t)dW_t$ with $X_0=x$.

Assume that $b$ and $\sigma$ are Lipschitz Continuous.

I want to proof that there exists $0<L$ such that $E\left|X_t^x\right|^2$ $\leq$ $Le^L$$^t$.

I think it's called a uniform boundary.

I have tried to apply Gronwall's Lemma (from ODE) in several ways, but I'm not sure it applies to SDE.

Comment: It is possible to prove the result using Gronwall's lemma. so where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @saz : 
Well 1st: I have never seen a proof that Gronwall's Lemma applies to Ito's Integral.

2nd: All my versions of the lemma consists with one function which is Lipschitz and the other is uniformly bounded by another function.

Comment: Step 1: Apply Itô's formula to calculate the differential $d(X_t^2)$. Step 2: Use Itô's isometry and Jensen's inequality. Step 3. Apply Gronwall's lemma for the function $u(t) := \mathbb{E}(|X_t|^2)$. (Or just have a look at the literature; there are plenty of books on this topic and many of them cover this result.)